# How to convert OpenGL code to WebGL

Tags: webgl

I have done a graphics project using OpenGL and now I want to convert It into WebGL so that I can put it on the web. Is there any way to directly convert the OpenGL c++ codes to WebGL or I have to re-write manually ??
I have learnt only some basics of WebGL as I am also learning javascript in parallel(only because it is required in coding webgl).
And any other suggestions are also welcomed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki). It's not a perfect solution, and depending on how your code is structured and what libraries you use you may have to do some manual tweaking, but it works pretty well as a generic C++ to Javascript cross compiler.

I make no promises that it's a magic bullet, but it may be worth a look.

Comment: thanks a lot.. :) I am trying to work with Emscripten... lets see what happen.
I am using glut libraries.

Comment: Do you have any updates on how this worked for you?  I'm taking a class that is strictly OpenGL but I'm hoping to convert my final project into a web-based version...

Comment: Let me add desktop GL has [an old deprecated fixed function API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35802910/128511) that requires some work to emulate if you happen to still be using it.

Answer (score 5):

It's a commercial solution but [Mandreel](http://www.mandreel.com/) will do this. It even emulates OpenGL ES 1.1 fixed function support on WebGL. There's also [Emscripten](http://emscripten.org/) which will convert the C/C++ and apparently has **some** old [OpenGL support](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/OpenGL-support).

Otherwise,

1. You're going to have to convert the C++ to JavaScript of course
2. If you used the old fixed function features of old OpenGL (glVertex, glColor, etc..) you'll have to convert them to use the newer programmable style of OpenGL 4 and OpenGL ES 2.0

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will have to see my budget for Mandreel. But it is really great.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your application is trivial, the bulk of your problem is going to be converting C++ code into JavaScript. C++ and JavaScript are quite different languages, e.g. one being statically typed and the other being dynamically typed.

WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, which is roughly a subset of OpenGL 2.0. So you can write OpenGL code that is direcly translatable, but not all OpenGL code is. It's difficult to know how easy the porting of the OpenGL code will be without more information.

I am not aware of any tools to automate the job for you, and I would be very skeptical to such tools if I saw them. Mapping the semantics of one programming language or API to another is a very difficult task to automate.

Comment: kusma and @SpliFF
Thanks for replying . Actually I have created a walk through of a building and now I want to publicize it over the net and that's why I need webGL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking manual rewriting is required. There isn't much chance a generic solution would correctly interpret existing code. Of course you could write your own converter since you have the benefit of only dealing with your own code and structures.

It's also worth mentioning that WebGL is a subset of OpenGL ES 2.0 so code written for desktop systems won't necessarily be compatible anyway.

The closest I've seen is code for converting OBJ models into WebGL code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that http://asmjs.org/ can be a basis for running non-javascript code in the browser.

Emscriptem (already mentioned), I think, can understand LLVM which can be output by some C++ compilers, but it probably needs manual work as well, the way these things go.

I've never used any of these but read about them and they seem interesting and trying to reach what you are trying to achieve, I can't say anything about the implementation and how they work in the "real world".